# Return a common value for another column based on a column of duplicate values

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Column 1   Column 2  (Desired Result Column)
1          A          1 and 2
1          B          1 and 2
1          C          null
2          A          1 and 2
2          B          1 and 2
2          C          null
2          A          1 and 2
1          B          1 and 2
1          A          1 and 2
1          B          1 and 2
3          A          null
3          B          null
3          C          null
```

The task is to only focus on values "1" and "2" from column 1 and where those values share the same value from column 2 to return the shared value from column 2 (this is a sample of the data, there are 7,000+ rows with values 1-80 in column 1 (but only specific values are needed for this comparison) and column 2 has about 45 values. I tried to do:

[When Column 2 Value "A" or "B" has value of "1 and 2" individually and in those instances result as "A" or "B"]

Basically need to be able to evaluate when Column 2 value of "A" has both "1" and "2" value result in column 1 and the same for "B" (singled

```
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    CONTAINSSTRING ( Table1[Column1], "1" )
        && CONTAINSSTRING ( Table1[Column1], "2" ), "CONTAINS 1 AND 2",
    "null"
)
```

but all results were null and I'm assuming my logic was wrong (also I didn't know how to bring in the value from column 2 for this comparison)

Also tried:

```
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    EXACT (
        LOOKUPVALUE ( Table1[Column2], Table1[Column1], "1" ),
        LOOKUPVALUE ( Table1[Column2], Table1[Column1], "2" )
    ), "CONTAINS A AND B",
    "null"
)
```

Got error: Table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

Comment: It's not clear what you're tyring to do. Both of your DAX expressions are nonsensical and don't even have the possibility to output `A` or `B` which you've specified in your desired result column.

Comment: I understand, I'm just lost and wanting to know if there is a way to do it. I understand my logic is nonsensical, it's just what I thought to try.

Comment: Well, it's hard to help when it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Basically the comparison of Column 1 with column 2 when column 2 value of "A" equals "1 and 2" and same for "B' (but in a generic sense and not literally if possible. Like is there a way to output common value result?

Comment: Hopefully some of the nonsense was caught in that last edit (not the expressions just overall ask)

Comment: Why is C null? It matches up to 1 and 2 also.

Comment: Only need to evaluate on "A" and "B", creating a selective constraint to the problem